# Fill html form by value with C# selenium

Tags: c#, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I try catching the html form to fill it out.

Here is the target html source.

```
<span class="login-id">
  <div id="LoginId">
     <input maxlength="100" name="uji.model.635939.value">
     <input type="hidden" name="uji.model" value="uji.model.635939">
     <input type="hidden" name="uji.model.635939"    value="com.fujitsu.uji.compo.taglib.FieldStringUpdater;vkaiinNinshoID">
  </div>
  <span class="example">（半角英数字）</span>
</span>
```

I focus on   `<input maxlength="100" name="uji.model.635939.value">` .
And the number `635949` is changed when I connect every time.

And here is my code. I used `for` to handle multiple cases.

```
for (int i = 600000; i < 699999; i++)
{
    string s = i.ToString();
    try
    {
        IWebElement id = driver.FindElement(By.Name(String.Format("uji.model.{0}.value", s)));
        id.SendKeys("******@gmail.com");
    }
    catch(OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("exception {0}", s);
    }
}
```

I wonder my code is correct. I'm not sure`(By.Name(String.Format("uji.model.{0}.value", s)` is correct.

BTW, `maxlength="100"` is the unique expression in the html source. 
Is there any way to fill out the form using this? Thank you for reading.

Comment: I think it actually failing that it cant find element is that right?

Comment: You can try to use regex to find the number like `(?<!\d)\d{6}(?!\d)` instead of looping and finding

Comment: Could you explain me the usage of regex for selenium in more detail? Filling the form is success but it takes long time.

Comment: why don't you try simple css Selector - `driver.FindElement(By.cssSelector("input[name^='uji.model.']")).SendKeys("your_Text");` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to locate the element is an expensive operation. Currently you are doing this up to 100K times, and catch an exception for all the failures, another expensive operation. There also might be numbers not in the specified range.

I suggest you locate the element using its parent element with unique id

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#LoginId > input:nth-child(1)"));
```

This will give you the first `<input>` child of `<div id="LoginId">`

If you don't want to use index, look for an element with `value` in the `name` attribute

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#LoginId > input[name*='value']"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I need to learn more about CssSelector syntax.